# I am trying to display a result in a GUI Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox

I have a working text editor with GUI that counts the amount of each word in a certain .txt file. I even have a special button for counting words called "Analyze". When I click it, it should display the result on a new window, not in the cocnsole. I am aware that "print()" shows the result the code in the console. But I can not find a way to disply it in the GUI. When I click "Analyze" button, the window should pop out and show the result.  I am using Python 3.8 on PyCharm Community edition 2019.3.2

```
import string
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog, END, messagebox, simpledialog
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText
from tkinter import *

root = Tk (className = " Text Editor")
textArea = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(root, width = 100, height = 50)
textArea.pack()

def newFile():
    if len(textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')) > 0:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Save", "Would you like to save?"):
            saveFile()
        else:
            textArea.delete('1.0', END)
    root.title("TEXT EDITOR")
def OpenFile():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent = root, title = 'Select a text file', filetypes = (("Text file", ".txt"),("All files", "*.*")))
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textArea.insert('1.0', contents)
        file.close()

def saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')

    if file!= None:
        data = textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
def exit():
    if messagebox.askyesno("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()
def about():
    label = messagebox.showinfo("About", "A simple text editor 0.1")
```

The problem is with the function above. I want it to display the results on an external window.

```
def AnalyzeData():
    text = open("dest.txt", "r")


    d = dict()

    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()

        line = line.lower()

        line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

        words = line.split(" ")


        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1

    for key in list(d.keys()):
        print(key, ":", d[key])
```

.

```
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
FMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = FMenu)
FMenu.add_command(label = "New", command = newFile)
FMenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = OpenFile)
FMenu.add_command(label = "Save", command = saveFile)
FMenu.add_separator()
FMenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = exit)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label = "Help")
menu.add_cascade(label = "Analyze", command = AnalyzeData)
menu.add_cascade(label = "Create Plot")
menu.add_cascade(label = "About", command = about)

textArea.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is use `messagebox.showinfo()`:

```
messagebox.showinfo('Analyze Data', '\n'.join(key+':'+str(val) for key, val in d.items()))
```

to replace the code:

```
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

But the message box may be very long that does not fit the screen height.

So better use `Text` widget in a `Toplevel` window:

```
win = tk.Toplevel(root)
win.geometry('+%s+%s' % (root.winfo_x()+100, root.winfo_y()+50))
win.transient(root)
result = tk.Text(win, width=40, height=20)
result.pack()
for key in sorted(d.keys()):
    result.insert('end', '%s: %s\n' % (key, d[key]))
win.grab_set()
```